# When Iot Agent sends data within milliseconds, the values are not notified to Draco subscription

Tags: fiware-orion

Our device sends millisecond level telemetry data to Fiware.  The payload contains DeviceId, DeviceDateTime and Attribute values as follows:

```
{"humidity":50.5,"device_id":"WS-100","devicetime":"2020-06-08T17:38:35.629+5:30"}
```

But we have observed that millisecond level tracking is not available in MongoDB and also Fiware does not notify the Draco subscription when data received at millisecond level.  It only sends one payload per second.  This is our Draco subscription:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://52.172.34.29:1026/v2/subscriptions?options=skipInitialNotification' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath:  /' \
  -d '{
  "description": "Subscription",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": []
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://52.172.34.29:3003/v2/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [],
    "onlyChangedAttrs":true,
    "throttling": 5
  }
}'
```

Can you please let us know how to handle this millisecond changes in Orion subscription.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Milliseconds support is part of Orion backlog (see issues [#3412](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3412), [#2670](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2670) and [#432](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/432)) but it has not been implemented yet. I know there are people in the FIWARE community working on this feature, but I don't know when it will be available.

However, even if Orion doesn't support milliseconds natively, the application always has the option to manage it itself. For instance, using a `devicetimeMs` which value is an integer with time in milliseconds, included along with the other data when you send a telemetry measure. This is the typical workaround.

**UPDATE**: milliseconds support for `DateTime` attributes and metadata has been implemented. The feature will be avaiable in next Orion version (2.5.0) but it can be used right now if you get `:latest` container from dockerhub.

Comment: Thanks fgalan for your response.  We have adopted the workaround you have mentioned in issues #3412 and achieved the milliseconds level telemetry measure.  We have declared a new attribute named TimeInstant in Device registration as follows and passing the value as a string with Millisecond in it: "TimeInstant": {
 "type": "DateTimeWithMilis"
}

Comment: But the above workaround works only for the entity level TimeInstant, still the attribute level metadata TimeInstant value was missing Millisecond level value.  In order to overcome this, we modified  the constants.js file within node_modules/iotagent-node-lib/lib folder to DateTimeWithMilis: module.exports = {
    TIMESTAMP_ATTRIBUTE: 'TimeInstant',
    TIMESTAMP_TYPE: 'ISO8601',
    TIMESTAMP_TYPE_NGSI2: 'DateTimeWithMilis',

Comment: Our sample Draco payload has changed as follows: {"subscriptionId":"5efc495a809703ec705d2420",
 "data":[
   {
      "id":"motion002",
      "type":"Motion",
       "TimeInstant":{
       "type":"DateTimeWithMilis",
       "value":"2020-07-01T12:24:59.347Z",
        "metadata":{
            }
         },
       "count":{
       "type":"Integer",
        "value":1001,
        "metadata":{
               "TimeInstant":{
                  "type":"DateTimeWithMilis",
                  "value":"2020-07-01T12:24:59.347Z"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}

Comment: Need your expert advice and opinion on whether the above is a good and robust solution please?

Comment: Is this the same being discussed here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3666#issuecomment-650562182 ?

Comment: Yes fgalan, it is the same issue.  Looks like my team member has raised the same issue github too.